# Disable or modify input[date] default buttons/controls and datepicker

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `input` field of type `date` (for validation using `ngMessages`):

```
<input type="date" ng-model="info.date" id="datefield" class="input-field datepicker">
```

I am using my own Bootstrap datepicker.

I want to get rid of the default datepicker calendar and also the default buttons/controls that `input[date]` has:

[image]

How do I get rid of these?

In case I can't get rid of these, I am ok with using the default calendar datepicker that comes from AngularJS but how do I style these elements (calendar and buttons/controls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the spinner and picker you can use (In Chrome):

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}
```

You can find these pseudo elements by inspecting the shadow DOM:

[image: shadow DOM]

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jajocasiru/2/)

Comment: weird.. i can't see the shadow DOM

Comment: @taa I think you might need to [enable it](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#inspect-shadow-dom)